# how to make some parts of contents cannot be edited in html textarea

Tags: html, textarea, readonly

in my html page i have a texteare, and I'll write some contents to it, I want to some of contents can be modify but some cannot.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <div class="text">
    <textarea cols="50" rows="4" name="msg_content" id="msg_content" readonly="readonly">
        Hi, I am the contents that can be modified.
        Hi, the url cannot be modified.

        http://www.google.com
    </textarea>
  </div>
</html>
```

as you see I made one of propety of textarea is readonly, but in this case, the whole contents can not be modified.

could you please give me some advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That can not be done. But, you can mimic the effect of disabled text inside the text area using CSS.
Create a Div element and position it just below the text box and design it in a way that it looks as if it is a part of text box.

You need to tweak and play with CSS for this.

Check this out: http://css-tricks.com/creating-a-nice-textarea/
Sample: http://css-tricks.com/examples/StyledTextArea/

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you can use HTML5. With HTML5 you can utilize contenteditable=true/false property for specific element.

Here you go an example:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
 You can edit this text, 
 <p contenteditable="false">but not this one.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working in IE11: http://plnkr.co/edit/eRhuzAwcxCVaLsbMn6sY?p=preview but works in Chrome and Firefox. Only Chrome shows a border when editing the content.